# Real analysis prove that the statements are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis

The following is the problem:

For a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ show that the following three statements are equivalent:

1. $f$ is one-to-one
2. $f(A\cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B) \ \ \forall \ \ A,B \in \mathcal{P} (X)$
3. For every pair of disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ we have $f(A)\cap f(B) = \emptyset$

So if one proves that $1 \implies 2$ and $2 \implies 3$ and $3 \implies 1$, then one has proven the equivalence of the statements.

In the problem solution (that $1 \implies 2$), the solver proceeds to note that if $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$ then $\exists \ \ a \in A$  and $b \in B$ with $y=f(a)=f(b)$. I do not follow this step, because $A$ and $B$ can be chosen to be disjoint and then this statement will not hold. I think I might be missing the implication of $1$. (i.e. that $f$ is one-to-one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$$
y \in f(A) \cap f(B)
$$
then $y$ is in both $f(A)$ and $f(B)$, by definition of intersection.

Since
$$
f(A) = \{ f(a) | a \in A \}
$$
every element of it is $f(a)$ for some $a \in A$. A similar argument applies to $B$.

To address your objection: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, it's still possible for $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ to intersect. Consider the squaring function on the reals: $f([-2, -1]) = f([1, 2])$, even though the two sets are disjoint.

Of course, for a 1-1 function it's impossible...and that's what the proof is showing, by contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question if you do not mind. I can now understand the above reasoning. They then proceed to say that since $f$ is one-to-one, then $a=b \in A \cap B$, fair enough. And thus $y \in f(A\cap B)$, also fair enough. But then the next step is strange. They say: "Thus, $f(A) \cap f(B) \subseteq f(A\cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$.". I understand that that statement implies equality. But I have no idea how they arrived at it.

Comment: we have that $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$ and we also have that $y \subseteq f(A \cap B)$. But how does that imply the above statement.

Comment: They've taken an arbitrary element $y$ in the first set, and shown that it must be in the second set (by the argument I gave). The fact that $f(A\cap B) \subset f(A) \cap f(B)$ is much easier: since $A \cap B \subset A$, we have $f(A\cap B) \subset f(A)$. Similarly, it's a subset of $f(B)$. Hence every element in it is in both $f(A)$ and in $f(B)$, so it's in $f(A) \cap f(B)$. That proves the second containment claim.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly! If $f$ is one-to-one and $A,B$ are disjoint, then $f(A)\cap f(B)=f(A\cap B)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. In particular, whenever $A,B$ are distinct singletons, ie, whenever $x\neq y$, then $f(x)\neq f(y)$, for otherwise $f(\{x\})\cap f(\{y\})$ would be nonempty.

At this point, I think it's important to point out the contrapositive; that is, proving $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ is (logically) equivalent to proving $\neg(2)\Rightarrow\neg(1)$.